# Cannot get List Lookup XSL param to use in HTML tag using SharePoint 2010 Designer

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

So I am adding a span tag to a few column fields in a couple of view all forms in SP 2010 Designer that have a Hexadec string in them, i'm using an inline style to display a block with a coloured background rather than the hexadec itself, so pretty simple.

I successfully achieved this in the first view but in the second view I cannot seem to return the value to use in the inline style, below is the original xsl and the row param is thisNode.  The only difference in the views is one is the view all for a custom list(this one is working) and the other is the view all for another custom list with the previous lists value as a Lookup column, the columns xsl value is below.

```
<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

I have tried adding the {$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]} to the inline css but get nothing returned when I should see a block of colour when viewing the form.  I have also tried other ways to get the value from the thisNode row but have had no luck, can anyone tell me what I should be doing or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out!

So the first step was to remove the hyperlink around the Loopup column:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name],'&gt;'), '&lt;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

This then shows the Lookup column value as text; so we can use this method to create another param or variable and add the value to our css parameter like so:

```
<xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
<xsl:param name="thisColour" select="substring-before(substring-after($thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name],'&gt;'), '&lt;')"/>
<span style="display:block;background:{$thisColour};width:20px;height:20px;" title=""></span>
```

This then shows my Hexadec colour as a 20px block rather than the Hexadec code as text, so hope this helps anyone else with the same problem, enjoy!